# Trying to wrap my head around PowerShell - functions, aliases etc

Tags: git, function, powershell, alias

I'm a seasoned C# programmer, but so far, I have only barely dabbled in PowerShell (having used another alternate Windows command line product so far).

I'm trying to automate some Git stuff, and I've run into some difficulties and can't seem to find any solution to these... (and no video tutorial or blog post seems to have helped much so far, either).

What I'm trying to do is define functions and aliases that make my work with Git in PowerShell more comfortable - and yes, I know about **Posh-Git**, and have checked it out, too - but that seems to be dealing mostly with presenting a nice UI in PowerShell.

I would like to define "shortcuts" for common Git command that I use all the time - and have successfully defined *some* aliases so far.

What I'm struggling with right now is this: I'd like to have an alias for `git pull` (and also `git push`), that can either run just "as is" - e.g. running just `git pull`, or that can run the most frequent command I need to use - `git pull origin master`.

I tried to define *one* function:

```
function invoke-gitpull { git pull $args }
```

and then define two aliases for this - one just calling this function "as is", one providing two parameters - like this:

```
Set-Alias gtp invoke-gitpull 
Set-Alias gtpom invoke-gitpull origin master
```

But somehow, PS doesn't like this :-(

> Set-Alias : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'origin'.
>   + Set-Alias gtpom invoke-gitpull origin master
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Alias], ParameterBindingException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAliasCommand

I then also tried to define parameters for the `invoke-gitpull` function - like this:

```
function invoke-gitpull ([String] $remote, [String] $branch) { git pull $remote $branch }
```

thinking that if I provide *no parameter values*, then `git pull` will be issued - and if I provide two param values - `invoke-gitpull -remote origin -branch master`, then `git pull origin master` would be called - but again, PS disagrees with me:

> Set-Alias : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'remote'.
>   + Set-Alias gtpom invoke-gitpull -remote origin -branch master
>   +                                ~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Alias], ParameterBindingException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAliasCommand

Also I then also tried with parameters *inside* the function:

but I got the same error again.

So **HOW** do I have to define those parameters for my `invoke-gitpull` function for this to work? I seem to be going in circles, not exactly understanding what I'm doing wrong..... can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Aliases* (using the `*-Alias` cmdlets) are limited to point at command names *only*, **without arguments**.  If you wish to have arguments to your alias as another alias (such as `gtp origin master`), you need to define them as *functions*:

```
function invoke-gitpull { git pull $args }
Set-Alias -Name gtp -Value invoke-gitpull
function gtpom { gtp origin master }
```

but if this is just a private-use thing, I'd skip aliases and just include them in your `$Profile` how you want them:

```
function gtp() { & GIT.exe pull @args }
function gtpom() { gtp origin master }
```

Comment: I did that - and it works OK - but I keep getting warnings when launching PS about having commands that are "not easily discoverable" since they're not using the standard verb-noun syntax ......

Comment: @marc_s unfortunately that's a limitation of aliases unless you creation function/alias combo for each one you want. I'm unsure how to suppress the warning but I'll do some research when I have a PC available.

Comment: @marc_s Are you defining these functions/aliases in a module and importing them into your profile?  If so, you can suppress the warning stream by redirecting it: `ipmo mymodule 3>$null`

Comment: Yes, I'm defining those functions and aliases in my own module and importing it

Comment: @marc_s Then yes, that's a feature of the `Import-Module` cmdlet.  You have three workarounds: suppress warnings with `3>$null`, `-WarningAction Ignore`, or define a function (conforming to verbs) / alias combo for each alias you want.

Comment: @marcs and TheIncorrigible1: Note that it's only _functions_ [imported from modules] that are subject to the name check - there are no constraints on _alias_ names. Also, `Import-Module` has a dedicated `-DisableNameChecking` switch to suppress the warning; however, that won't help you when importing modules with `using module ...`. By contrast, if a module is _auto_-loaded - by virtue of being placed in a folder listed in `$env:PSModulePath` - the warning is _not_ shown.